# Access Invocations reference using Roslyn

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn

I want to create a *Visual Studio Extension(VSIX)* using **Roslyn**. This extension should find all invocations, then looks for their definitions to analyse attributes defined on them. The definition of the method can be any where in the solution.

My first class is like this:

```
namespace MainProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(BusinessProject.Calc.AddNumbers(5, 8));
        }
    }
}
```

My second class is something like the following:

```
namespace BusinessProject
{
    public class Calc
    {
        [CustomAttr("Do something")]
        public static long AddNumbers(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

In above sample, in class **Program**, I have an invocation of **AddNumbers** method. I want to 1) analyse the code, 2) find this invocation, 3) get all attributes of the reference method in class **Calc**, 4) process attributes parameters, 5) and then make a warning/error if needed.
I can analyse current class to find all invocations by *RegisterCodeBlockAction*, But what I can't do is accessing the entire solution to find definition of the invocation and after that, accessing attributes of the reference.

How can I access the entire solution in *RegiserCodeBlockAction*?

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the wrong method.

You actually want your analyzer to run on every method invocation, not every code block.
Therefore, you should call [`RegisterSyntaxNodeAction`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/DiagnosticAnalyzer/DiagnosticAnalysisContext.cs,ef9f92f22a79f3d6), and pass `SyntaxKind.InvocationExpression`.

It will then call you with an `InvocationExpressionSyntax` which has all the information you need (mostly in the Semantic Model).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but how can I access the definition of the method? This method can be declared any where of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

As @SLaks mentioned in his comment, by using **SemanticModel.Compilation.SyntaxTrees** we can access all of the source codes in solution. I found the method and its parameters. But this has a problem which you can't get the TypeInfo of objects using **SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo**. You have to create a new *Semantic Model* like as follows:

```
foreach (var tree in context.SemanticModel.Compilation.SyntaxTrees)
{
    var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyCompilation",
                    syntaxTrees: new[] { tree }, references: new List<MetadataReference>());
    var syntaxRoot = tree.GetRoot();
    var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
    var targetMethod = syntaxRoot.DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Identifier.ToString() == "Class name to find");
    if (targetMethod == null)
        continue;

    var typeInfo = model.GetTypeInfo(targetMethod.First().ParameterList.Parameters[i].ChildNodes().First());
    // Do any thing with typeInfo
}
```